# How to handle null exception in dataGridView1_SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I am getting the following error in `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event. For the first selection it works, but if I change the selection I get the error:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code is as follows. Please correct me where I made mistake:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowindex;
        // MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index.ToString());
        rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;   //error        
        if (rowindex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex];
            txtpaX.Text = row.Cells["X"].Value.ToString();
            txtpaY.Text = row.Cells["Y"].Value.ToString();
            lblinfo.Text = row.Cells["item"].Value.ToString();

            xposition = int.Parse(txtpaX.Text);
            yposition = int.Parse(txtpaY.Text);
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In runtime this event called during initialization meanwhile your datagrid is empty. What you may do is putting a flag at the end of your form load event which differentiates the initialization of the form from other methods and events. Then put a condition covering this event with that flag.

Comment: This sounds fishy, pretty unclear exactly *how* you changed the selection.  Do keep in mind that you could be hiding a bigger bug, updating the data source on a bound DGV from a worker thread can corrupt the internal state of DGV, also causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
   {

   }
```

Also, you need to check for a null reference when you set your `.Text` properties, otherwise you may get a null reference exception.

So the final code would look like...

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
    {
        int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        if (rowindex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex];
            if (row.Cells["X"].Value != null) txtpaX.Text = row.Cells["X"].Value.ToString();
            if (row.Cells["Y"].Value != null) txtpaY.Text = row.Cells["Y"].Value.ToString();
            if (row.Cells["item"].Value != null) lblinfo.Text = row.Cells["item"].Value.ToString();

            xposition = int.Parse(txtpaX.Text);
            yposition = int.Parse(txtpaY.Text);
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```